# poplib.error_proto: -ERR Protocol error. 17

Tags: python, pop3

I try to get emails with python poplib, but I get:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/poplib.py", line 189, in pass_
    return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/poplib.py", line 152, in _shortcmd
    return self._getresp()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/poplib.py", line 128, in _getresp
    raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: -ERR Protocol error. 17
```

The POP3 server is Microsoft Exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case there was a non-ASCII character in the password. The admin created a new password for me, and now all works well.

Related: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrgeneral/thread/e5badd24-2d11-4bdd-a746-3aee50242ccb